# Search algorithm (with a sort algorithm already implemented)

Tags: java, algorithm, search, sorting

Im doing a Java application and Im facing some doubts in which concerns performance.

I have a PriorityQueue which guarantees me the element removed is the one with greater priority. That PriorityQueue has instances of class **Event** (which implements Comparable interface). Each Event is associated with a **Entity**.

The size of that priorityqueue could be huge and very frequently I will have to remove events associated to an entity.

Right now Im using an iterator to run all the priorityqueue. However Im finding it heavy and I wonder if there are better alternatives to search and remove events associated with an entity "xpto".

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few options:

1. Could you use separate queues for
   each entity? So when you get an
   event for "xpto" you put it into the
   XptoPriorityQueue? This will reduce
   the size of each queue, but could
   also lead to some other management
   issues.
2. Are you removing events for
   a specific entity to process them
   sooner? If so then you should simply
   give those entities a higher
   priority and bump them to the top of
   the queue.
3. Are you removing events
   for a specific entity to remove them
   from the queue and ignore them? If
   so then they should either never get
   into the queue or should get a lower
   priority.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Its the 3rd option. This application is related to evolutive programming. I have 3 kinds of events: reproduction, mutation and death. Those three kinds of events are added randomly to the priorityqueue (priority is defined by event's time). However when a death event ocurrs, all those events that are in the priorityqueue and have less priority must be removed. 
Prevent other events to be added before death event is not so straight forward in my case, I think...

Comment: Must they be removed from the queue or should they just not be processed??? 

If you pull an event off the queue that is "dead" just discard it and get the next one.

Naturally this assumes that theres a way to check if any given event is dead.

Comment: The events must be removed. Otherwise the priorityqueue will be HUGE arising the risk of "out of memory" and add or poll events from PriorityQueue will take more time.

Comment: What yo ucould do is to keep a small amount of extra state (for "dead entities") and keep tabs on the size of the priority queue. 
When getting an event from the queue for a dead entity, ignore it and get he next. If the queue hits a pre-defined limit (or if you get sufficient number of now-dead entities), scan the whole priority queue and remove all events relating to dead entities.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Implement your priority queue using a treap ordered by the entity's key. If the keys are randomly distributed then you should be able to remove elements in O(log n) time.
2. Maintain a separate mapping of Entity to Events currently in the queue. Instead of actually removing events from the queue immediately, just flip a bit on the Event object indicating it should be ignored when it reaches the front of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Since `remove` is a linear time operation, you are getting O(N*N) performance.

If you subclass `PriorityQueue` and create a new method (named `removeIf` perhaps) that combines the iterator and `remove` methods then you could reduce this to O(N log(N)).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you make a class composed of a PriorityQueue and a Set, with the following operations:

- To add an element, remove it from the Set and, if it weren't there, add it to the PriorityQueue.
- To remove an element, add it to the Set.
- To unqueue an element, unqueue elements from the PriorityQueue until the unqueued element is not present in the Set. Remove any unqueued elements from the Set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to implement a souped-up priority queue.  In particular, you need O(logN) removal time.  You can do this by keeping two data structures, an array of Events which is basically the [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) storing your priority queue, and a HashMap from Event to the offset of that Event in the array (or maybe from Entity to a list of offsets of Events in that array).

You can then do normal heap operations as you would for a priority queue, you just need to update the hash map mappings every time an Event is moved.  To remove an Event, look up the index of that event in the hash table and do a remove operation on the heap starting at that index.